# How to stroke a path in Core Graphic?

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

I'm trying to stroke my path by writing below line of code but its not getting drawn. Please help me to find out whats the problem in this.

```
void draw1PxStroke(CGContextRef context,CGColorRef color,CGMutablePathRef arcPath) {
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapSquare);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0);
    CGContextAddPath(context, arcPath);
    CGContextClip(context); 
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);                
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is probably your call to `CGContextClip` which has the side effect of resetting the context's current path to an empty path.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.origin.x + rect.size.width, rect.origin.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.origin.x + rect.size.width, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

This will display a square